# Where can I find the default configuration of Home Assistant?

Tags: home-assistant

I decided I should start version controlling my Home Assistant configuration, and want to commit the unedited config first to see what changes I already made. Can I find a complete copy unedited of the config folder (and other relevant files if any) anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This official guide](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/ecosystem/backup/backup_github/) suggests that only the `config` directory should be version controlled and also a specific `.gitignore`. This, applied to a fresh install of Home Assistant 0.105.3, leaves five files:

- `groups.yaml`, `scenes.yaml` and `scripts.yaml`, all empty
- `automations.yaml`, containing only `[]`
- `configuration.yaml`, with the following contents:

```
# Configure a default setup of Home Assistant (frontend, api, etc)
default_config:

# Uncomment this if you are using SSL/TLS, running in Docker container, etc.
# http:
#   base_url: example.duckdns.org:8123

# Text to speech
tts:
  - platform: google_translate

group: !include groups.yaml
automation: !include automations.yaml
script: !include scripts.yaml
scene: !include scenes.yaml
```